# Remove special characters in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a number like

`$mynum = "(800)-756-1235";`

I want to remove all the special characters and only want the numbers here.
How to do it in perl?

Comment: Do you want 3 separate numbers or one number with the non digit characters removed?

Answer (score 5):

This regular expression will remove all non-digit characters.

```
$mynum =~ s/\D+//g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the value of `$mynum` is a string, not a number, so your code should be something like

```
$mynum = '(800)-756-1235';
$mynum =~ s/\D+//g;
```

After removed all the no-digit characters from `$mynum`, if you use `$mynum` as a number, Perl will convert it to a number automatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $num = '(800)-765-1235';
$num =~ y/0-9//cd;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just learned this not too log ago, so here you go.

You can use a regex to match just the numbers like so, and assign the values elsewhere.

```
my $num = "(800)-765-1235";

my @newNum = $num =~ /\d+/g;
```

You can then `join('', @newNum)` to get your phone number.

You could also do `my $newNum = join('', $num =~ /\d+/g)`. But that gets difficult to read.

edit - removed unneeded parenthesis.

Comment: Actually, in this particular case, the parentheses are optional.

Comment: @TLP mind ... blown. tested and you are correct. Care to share why in this case the parenthesis aren't needed?

Comment: The `/g` modifier does this. Although its of course not wrong to leave the parentheses there.

Comment: perlop: `The "/g" modifier specifies global pattern matching--that is, matching as many times as possible within the string. How it
behaves depends on the context. In list context, it returns a
list of the substrings matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression. If there are no parentheses, it returns
a list of all the matched strings, as if there were parentheses
around the whole pattern.`